# How to exclude a class from Spring using new Condition interface?

Tags: java, spring

Often we have tests and production environment different from each other. Depending on some configuration parameters, certain classes are not required to be registered as beans by container (while using spring). Is there a way to dynamically skip such classes from application context ?

Comment: Why won't you use the mechanism that's available out of the box: profiles?

Answer (score 0):

Using Spring 4 @Conditional annotation we can.

Check [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/annotation/Condition.html) for details of Spring Condition interface

First create a Class say- "ComponentScanCondition which implements Spring's "Condition" interface. And the only method "matches" returns false if the system property is not null or it is a "test" environment.

```
public class ComponentScanCondition implements Condition{

@Override
public boolean matches(ConditionContext context, AnnotatedTypeMetadata metaData) {

    return System.getProperty("environment")!=null && System.getProperty("environment").equals("test")? false:true;

}


}
```

Now with annotation- @Conditional(ComponentScanCondition.class) you can control the component scan on the classes you do not need in test environment.

In jUnit test class, set up a system property as below:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(locations = {"classpath:applicationContext.xml"})
public class testMyClass{

 @BeforeClass
 public static void setUpBeforeClass() throws Exception{
  System.setProperty("environment", "test");
 }

 @Test
 public void testSomeMethod(){

 }


}
```

**And in the classes, not required in test, use @Conditional annotation**.For example if you do not need UserProfile class in test environment, skip it as below:

```
@service("userProfile")
@Conditional(ComponentScanCondition.class)
public class UserProfile{

}
```

As in test class the system property "environment" is set to "test", matches method will return false and Spring will skip the class UserProfile to be scanned.

**In prod environment this property will not be set and will be null so matches will return true and hence UserProfile (and those class with @Conditional) will be scanned by Spring to register as beans in the container**.

Answer (score 0):

**If the class that should been used in the test is only available the classpath while testing**, and your problem is about replacing injected classes, then you could annotate the class that is used in TESTs with [@Primary](http://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring-framework/4.0.4.RELEASE/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/annotation/Primary.html) annotation.

[@Primary](http://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring-framework/4.0.4.RELEASE/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/annotation/Primary.html) is a feature of spring that is much older then conditions and less powerful but it is really easy to use. Is says: when an injection point 
could been fulfilled with two Beans then use the bean that is annotated with `@Primary`, instead throwing an exception that complains about ambiguous beans.

So when you add a bean in test scope with `@Primary` annotation, then this bean replaces the original bean in its injection points.

Comment: You can set the primary flag in xml too.

Comment: @Steer360; Please read my answer again, specially  the first paragraph.

Comment: I read. I cannot replace the injected class. The injected classes are required. And if for test i have to annotate with @Primary, then when it is in production, will i have to remove that annotation from the class?. My purpose is to make it dynamically, whatever i annotate should work seamlessly for both prod and test. please advise.

Comment: @Steer360: The idea was, that the Class used in the test in only available in the test class path (in maven: src/test/java) - If this is not the case for you, then my idea does not work for you.

Comment: Yes its not just available only for test. Thanks Ralph !